# Excel export from Pentaho Report Designer missing commas

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Using Report Designer, when I preview the data in a PDF, the number formatting for PDF is correct in which there is a thousands separator--a comma after 3 digits--but the Excel output has it missing.

Excel - 857320
PDF   - 857,320

What changes can be made to the attributes so that the comma is present for the Excel export as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting #,##0 in format of the attributes of number-field gets the comma after 3 digits. 
It seems in pdf it would work even without this format specification but for excel export it needs to be there.